# How do I delete selected rows from a dataframe that are in a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, analytics

I'm trying to delete rows with no value from a dataframe using Python and pandas.

The selected rows are currently in a variable but it needs to be dropped from the df.

I've tried new_df.dpop but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

```
novalue_df = new_df[new_df['age'].isnull() & (new_df['churn'] == 
False) & (new_df['avgBill'] < 40)]
```

Comment: Can you please show an example df? It looks like you're actively selecting null values.

Comment: You should just be able to select the rows that meet the inverse of the condition you posted : `good_df = new_df[~(new_df['age'].isnull() & (new_df['churn'] == 
False) & (new_df['avgBill'] < 40))]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `~` symbol to invert your boolean mask.

```
filtered_df = new_df[~(new_df['age'].isnull() 
                       & new_df['churn'] == False 
                       & new_df['avgBill'].lt(40))]
```

To "delete" the rows, you can just reassign the result to the original variable's name:

```
new_df = new_df[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

First option: use `novalue_df` index to select the rows

```
df = new_df.loc[novalue_df.index]
```

Second: reindex (effectively the same):

```
df = new_df.reindex(novalue_df.index)
```

Third: similar to Alexander's answer, discarded